# Representing measurable map to compact space as a continuous map

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, von-neumann-algebras, gelfand-duality

Let $\Omega$ be a measurable space equipped with a $\sigma$-ideal $\mathcal{N}$ (though of as the "null sets"). Define the compact Hausdorff space
$$ \tilde{\Omega} := \mathrm{Spec}(L^\infty(\Omega)), $$
where $\mathrm{Spec}$ denotes the Gelfand spectrum. In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99091/spectrum-of-l-inftyx-mu), Terry Tao mentions the following (universal?) property of $\tilde{\Omega}$: "any [modulo-null-sets-equivalence class of?] Baire-measurable map[s] from $\Omega$ to a compact Hausdorff space $K$ can be uniquely identified with a continuous map from $\tilde{\Omega}$ to K." I haven't been able to find a precise statement or proof in the given references (or elsewhere, where would I have to look precisely?). If $K$ is a compact subset of the real numbers, then this is a consequence of Gelfand duality. How would one proceed in the general case?

**EDIT:** Let's ask a (maybe) simpler question. Assume that $\Omega$ is itself a compact Hausdorff space equipped with a Radon probability measure. If necessary, suppose also that $\Omega$ and $K$ are metrizable. Then, via Gelfand duality, we obtain a continuous map
$f: \tilde{\Omega} \to \Omega $. $\tilde{\Omega}$ also inherits the probability measure from $\Omega$ and $f$ is measure preserving. Now the question becomes: Is $f$ a mod $0$ isomorphism of probability spaces? (If this were the case, then a version of the cited segment would be true.)

Comment: I think there is a subtlety that arises when the space $K$ is not metrizable, and in this case we cannot simply relate two Baire-measurable functions if they agree almost everywhere. For example, if $X$ is the underlying set of the measurable space and $f:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}^\mathcal{N}$ is the map where $f(x)=(\chi_A(x))_{A\in\mathcal{N}}$, then we should relate the function $f$ to the zero function, but $f$ does not agree with the zero function at any point.

Comment: I think the basic idea is that $K$ can be embedded in a product of compact intervals $\prod I_{\alpha}$, by sending $x\mapsto f_{\alpha}(x)$, with $\{ f_{\alpha} \} = C(K;\mathbb R)$. Now a bounded measurable function $g:\Omega\to K$ can be reinterpreted as a family of real-valued functions on $\Omega$, and the Gelfand theory takes care of those. (Obviously, there are many details that need to be addressed here.)

Comment: @JosephVanName Sorry, but I don't understand how this example is relevant. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I think the devil might be in those details. A reference would still be very welcome.

Comment: In my example, $f(x)\neq f(0)$ for each $x\in X$. On the other hand, $\pi_A\circ f=\chi_A$ which is equal to $0$ almost everywhere. This means that $\tilde{\pi_A\circ f}:\tilde{\Omega}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is the zero mapping. And the only way this is possible is if the induced mapping $\tilde{f}:\tilde{\Omega}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^\mathcal{N}$ is also the zero mapping.

Comment: The space $\tilde{\Omega}$ satisfies the extension property precisely when it is extremally disconnected. By Stone duality, $\tilde{\Omega}$ is extremally disconnected precisely when the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{I}$ is complete. But if $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{I}$ is complete, I can probably use a Boolean-valued model forcing argument to characterize the continuous maps from $\tilde{\Omega}$ to $K$.

Comment: @JosephVanName Thanks! So your example is a counterexample to (my interpretation of) the cited statement in the general case. What about the metrizable case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a precise formulation and proof of the cited statement.

Let's suppose for simplicity that $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space. Define the set of $K$-valued random variables up to almost sure equality (with $K$ some compact space),
$$ \mathrm{RV}(\Omega, K) := \{X: \Omega \to K \mid X \text{ Baire measurable} \}/(=_{a.e.}).$$

With $\tilde{\Omega}$ as in the question, the desired statement is:

**Theorem.** Let $K$ be a compact metrizable space. Then the ("Gelfand-duality-induced") map
$$ \Psi_K: \mathrm{RV}(\Omega, K) \to C(\tilde{\Omega}, K), \;\;\; X \mapsto (\tilde{\Omega}\ni \omega \mapsto \Gamma^{-1}((C_b(K) \ni f \mapsto \omega(f(X))), $$
is a bijection, where
$$ \Gamma^{-1}: \mathrm{Spec}(C_b(K)) \to K $$
is the inverse Gelfand transform.

**Proof.** As noted already in the question, the claim follows from Gelfand duality when $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, for any compact space $L$, we have that
$$ \mathrm{RV}(\Omega, L^\mathbb{N}) \to \mathrm{RV}(\Omega, L)^\mathbb{N}, \;\;\; X \mapsto (\pi_n(X))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, $$
is bijective. (For injectivity, we use that we consider a *countable* product $L^\mathbb{N}$, while for surjectivity, we use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem and compactness of $L$.) This yields the claim for the case of $K = L^\mathbb{N}$ with $L\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ (cf. the approach suggested by Christian Remling).
Finally, for the general case note that since $K$ is compact and metrizable, it admits an embedding,
$$ \iota: K \to [0,1]^\mathbb{N}, $$
into the Tychonov cube (Tychonov's embedding theorem), as well as a surjection (epimorphism in the category $\mathsf{CompHaus}$ of compact Hausdorff spaces),
$$ \pi: \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\to K,$$
from Cantor space (Hausdorff-Alexandrov theorem). This gives us the following commutative diagram (in $\mathsf{Set}$):
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathrm{RV}(\Omega, \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}) @>>> \mathrm{RV}(\Omega, K) @>>> \mathrm{RV}(\Omega, [0,1]^\mathbb{N}) \\
    @V{\Psi_{\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}}}VV @V{\Psi_K}VV @V{\Psi_{[0,1]^\mathbb{N}}}VV \\
    C(\tilde{\Omega}, \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}) @>{C(\tilde{\Omega}, \pi)}>> C(\tilde{\Omega}, K) @>{C(\tilde{\Omega},\,\iota)}>> C(\tilde{\Omega},\, [0,1]^\mathbb{N})
\end{CD}
Since $\tilde{\Omega}$ is extremely disconnected, it is projective in $\mathsf{CompHaus}$ (Gleason's theorem), so $C(\tilde{\Omega}, \pi)$ is surjective. With this, the square on the left gives us surjectivity of $\Psi_K$, while the square on the right yields injectivity.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is a completely regular frame, then let $\mathfrak{R}(L)$ denote the point-free Stone-Cech compactification of $L$. Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $L$ be the frame of all open sets in $X$. Let $B$ be a complete Boolean algebra.

Let $Z$ denote the collection of all frame homomorphisms $\phi:L\rightarrow B$. Then $Z$ is a $B$-valued structure. If $L$ is regular and compact, then
$V^B\models\text{$Z$ is a compact Hausdorff space}$, and $Z$ is the space that one would obtain by interpreting the space $X$ in the Boolean-valued forcing extension $V^B$ (when we interpret a compact Hausdorff space in a forcing extension, we usually need to add points to the space so that we retain compactness and we need to add open sets too).

Let $Z_1$ denote the collection of all frame homomorphisms $\phi:L\rightarrow\mathfrak{R}(B)$. Then by the universal property of the point-free Stone-Cech compactification, the set $Z_1$ can be put into a canonical one-to-one correspondence with $Z_1$. Let $Z_2$ be the collection of all continuous functions
$f:S(B)\rightarrow X$. Then $Z_2$ can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with $Z_1$ and $Z$ as well. We have more correspondences that are closer to the idea of equivalence classes of measurable functions. The collection of frame homomorphisms from $L$ to $B$ corresponds to the collection of all localic maps from $B$ to $L$:
If $f:L\rightarrow B$ is a frame homomorphism, then the corresponding localic map is the right Galois adjoint $f_*:B\rightarrow L$ defined by letting $f_*(b)=\bigvee\{x\mid f(x)\leq b\}$. The localic map $f_*$ preserves all infima.

**Congruence tower**

If $L$ is a frame, then the collection of all congruences on $L$ is another frame which we denote by $\mathfrak{C}(L)$. There is a homomorphism $\Delta:L\rightarrow\mathfrak{C}(L)$ where we set $(a,b)\in\Delta(x)$ precisely when $a\vee x=b\vee x$. We can iterate this process of taking congruence frames transfinitely and obtain $\mathfrak{C}^\alpha(L)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ where we set $\mathfrak{C}^0(L)=L$ and
$\mathfrak{C}^{\alpha+1}(L)=\mathfrak{C}(\mathfrak{C}^\alpha(L))$ and
$\mathfrak{C}^\lambda(L)=\text{Colim}_{\alpha<\lambda}\mathfrak{C}^\alpha(L)$ for each limit ordinal $\lambda$. This transfinite process generally does not terminate. In each case, we have a canonical homomorphism $\Delta^\alpha:L\rightarrow\mathfrak{C}^\alpha(L).$

If $L$ is a frame and $B$ is a complete Boolean algebra, then for each homomorphism $\phi:L\rightarrow B$, there is a unique frame homomorphism
$\overline{\phi}:\mathfrak{C}^\alpha(L)\rightarrow B$ where
$\phi=\overline{\phi}\Delta^\alpha$. In particular, the frame homomorphisms from $L$ to $B$ can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with the frame homomorphisms from $\mathfrak{C}^\alpha(L)$ to $B$.

**Baire functions induce our maps**

Recall that the Loomis-Sikorski theorem states that every $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra can be written as $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{I}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is a $\sigma$-ideal on a $\sigma$-algebra $(X,\mathcal{M})$, and I think it is quite natural to write a complete Boolean algebra as a

Suppose that $B$ is a complete Boolean algebra, and $B=\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{I}$ for some $\sigma$-algebra $(X,\mathcal{M})$ and
$\sigma$-ideal $\mathcal{I}$. Let $K$ be a compact space, and let $f:X\rightarrow K$ be a Baire function. Then whenever
$U$ is a co-zero set, we have $f^{-1}[U]\in\mathcal{M}$. Let $L$ be the lattice of open subsets of $B$, and let $G$ denote the sublattice of cozero subsets of $L$, and let $W$ denote the lattice of zero subsets of $L$. Define a mapping $f^\sharp:L\rightarrow\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{I}$ by letting
$f^\sharp(U)=\bigvee\{f^{-1}[V]\oplus\mathcal{I}:V\in G,V\subseteq U\}$. It is not too hard to show that
$f^\sharp(U)=\bigvee\{f^{-1}[V]\oplus\mathcal{I}:V\in G,\overline{V}\subseteq U\}=\bigvee\{f^{-1}[V]\oplus\mathcal{I}:C\in W,C\subseteq U\}.$

Suppose now that $C\in W,C\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha$. Then by compactness, there are $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r\in A$ where $C\subseteq U_{\alpha_1}\cup\dots\cup U_{\alpha_r}$. Each $U_{\alpha_i}$ is a union of countably many zero sets, so each set $C\cap U_{\alpha_i}$ is also the union of countably many zero sets $(C_{n,i})_{n=0}^\infty$. Therefore,
$f^{-1}[C]\oplus\mathcal{I}=\bigvee_{i=1}^r\bigvee_{n=0}^\infty f^{-1}[C_{n,i}]\oplus\mathcal{I}\leq f^\sharp(U_{\alpha_1})\vee\dots\vee f^\sharp(U_{\alpha_n})\leq\bigvee_{\alpha\in A}f^\sharp(U_\alpha)$. Therefore, we conclude that
$f^\sharp(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha)=\bigvee\{f^{-1}[C]\oplus\mathcal{I}:C\in W,C\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha\}\leq\bigvee_{\alpha\in A}f^\sharp(U_\alpha)$.

Therefore, $f^\sharp(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha)=\bigvee_{\alpha\in A}f^\sharp(U_\alpha)$.

If $U,V\in L$, then
$f^\sharp(U\cap V)=\bigvee\{f^{-1}[O]\oplus\mathcal{I}:O\in G,O\subseteq U\cap V\}$

$=\bigvee\{(f^{-1}[O_1]\cap f^{-1}[O_2])\oplus\mathcal{I}:O_1,O_2\in G,O_1\subseteq U,O_2\subseteq V\}$

$=\bigvee\{f^{-1}[O_1]\oplus\mathcal{I}:O_1\in G,O_1\subseteq U\}\wedge
\bigvee\{f^{-1}[O_2]\oplus\mathcal{I}:O_2\in G,O_2\subseteq V\}$

$=f^\sharp(U)\wedge f^\sharp(V)$.

Therefore, $f^\sharp$ is a frame homomorphism.

On the other hand, the mapping $f\mapsto f^\sharp$ from Baire maps modulo $\mathcal{I}$ to frame homomorphisms is generally non-injective

I claim that we can have two Baire functions $f,g:X\rightarrow K$ where $f^\sharp=g^\sharp$ but where $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.
Suppose that $K=\{0,1\}^\mathcal{I}$ and let
$f:X\rightarrow K$ be the mapping where $f(x)=(\chi_A(x))_{A\in\mathcal{I}}$. We observe that the Baire sets in $K$ are generated by the sets $\pi_A^{-1}[\{1\}]$ where $\pi_A:\{0,1\}^\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is the projection mapping. But $\pi_A\circ f=\chi_A$, so $f^{-1}[\pi_A^{-1}[\{1\}]]=\chi_A^{-1}[\{1\}]=A$, hence $f$ is Baire measurable. On the other hand, if $g:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}^\sharp$ is the zero function, then $f^\sharp(\pi_A^{-1}[\{1\}])=g^\sharp(\pi_A^{-1}[\{1\}])$ for all $A\in\mathcal{I}$, so $f^\sharp=g^\sharp$.

Comment: Thanks again for your interest, but I don't think this answers the question. (I guess this is a [partial?] answer to your own question of how to characterize the continuous maps from $\tilde{\Omega}$ to $K$?) I posted an answer to my own question, maybe you can review it and let me know if you think it's fine.

Comment: Even after your most recent edit, I still think your answer is unfortunately slightly off-topic. 1) The question is not about measurable maps inducing frame homomorphisms, so you would need to clarify how these in turn induce continuous maps of compact Hausdorff spaces under Stone duality (this won't be obvious to most readers, I promise). 2) It's not directly clear at all how the first two parts of your answer relate to the question.

Comment: Again, I appreciate your interest, but I fear your answer will likely be confusing for most future visitors...